# Integral from $\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I know there is the property that

$$\int_a^a f(x) \mathbb{d} x = 0$$

But what if $a=\infty$? Is the integral still necessarily zero even though infinity isn't well defined?

Comment: Like most things, it depends on how you've defined $\infty$ or $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Per the usual definition, this is only true when $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges for some $a$. However, the Cauchy principal value is indeed $0$ for any $f$.

Comment: What do you mean "infinity isn't well-defined?" It isn't a number. But that goes without saying.

Comment: In the complex plane it could mean (for example) a [Hankel contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_contour) (starting and ending at $+\infty$).

Answer (score 4):

$\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ is defined as $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

$\int_{-\infty}^b f(x)dx$ is defined as $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ is defined as  $\lim_{a\to-\infty,b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

These are conventional meanings, that everybody agrees on.

But $\int_\infty^\infty f(x)dx$ is not defined to mean anything at all. It is literally meaningless.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be defined as $\lim_{a\to\infty,b\to \infty} \int_a^b$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Well, I failed to notice this in my comment to Aniket's answer, but if this limit exists, then it must be equal to $\lim_{b\to\infty,a\to \infty} \int_a^b = \lim_{a\to\infty,b\to \infty} \int_b^a = \lim_{a\to\infty,b\to \infty} -\int_a^b$, so it must be zero. Hence not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ literally means nothing. Still according to conventional ways, you could say it like this :

$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx =\lim_\limits{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a}f(x) dx =\lim_\limits{a\to\infty} 0 = 0  $$

Comment: That would, I suppose, be the Principal Value of the integral (as opposed to the more natural definition $\lim_{a\to\infty,b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)dx$, which may or may not exist).

Comment: @TonyK Why principal value only? My definition is similar to yours and you have accepted in the above comment that the answer indeed is $0$ if it exists.

Comment: For a general function $F$, $\lim_{a\to\infty}F(a,a)$ is not the same as $\lim_{a\to\infty,b\to\infty}F(a,b)$. If the former exists, the latter may or may not exist (but if it does exist, then the two are equal). So in this case, the "Principal Value" always exists, but my "natural definition" may or may not exist. So we have something that must alway equal $0$; and someting else that, if it exists, must equal $0$. As I said, not very useful :-)

Answer (score 2):

Value of your integral depends on a definition of $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}$, for example, take

$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}0=0$$

but if we take some other boundaries, i.e.:

$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{\ln(a)}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$

it doesn't have to be equal to $0$. For example for $f(x)=1$:

$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}1\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}(a-\ln(a))=\infty$$

We can define it also as

$$\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

and the second limit $\lim\limits_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)dx$ doesn't have to exist at all.